# Disabling form submit prevents button attribute from being sent

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, laravel

I have a form with two submit buttons. I'm using the 'name' attribute to see which one is being clicked to submit the form. I want to disable the buttons upon submitting using jquery with the following function:

```
$(document).on('submit', '.js-form', function(e) {
   $(this).find('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

The problem is after doing this I'm finding that name attribute is not being sent anymore. I've checked the sent requests (in the network tab - chrome) and it is'nt being sent even though before it used to be sent with no problems.

can anyone tell me why that is and how I can overcome it?

thanks

Comment: Disabled elements are not submitted, you can disable the buttons after you've gotten the form data, but the code that submits the form is missing in your question.

Comment: Why not use 2 radio inputs for the `choice` and a single submit button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should disable the form from submitting by capturing its state. You can do this by adding a class to the form and if it has that class then stop the event.

```
 $(document).on('submit', '.js-form', function(e) {
     if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
         // Form is disabled, stop the event
         e.preventDefault();
         e.stopPropagation();
         return false;
     } else {
         // Allow first submit and add class to stop subsequent
         $(this).addClass('disabled');
     }
 });
```

This then does not clear or disable any button, allowing all the data to come through.

Answer (score 0):

Don't disable the submit button after the form has been submitted. Browsers already handle this for you technically. As soon as a form is submitted, the browser won't accept any other successful form submissions. Sure, a user can click the different buttons before the page loads, but it won't submit the form multiple times (unless you use ajax or a different solution).